# Framework for the generation of lattice meshes

Tags: c++, frameworks, mesh

I'm looking for a method to fill a surface mesh with a lattice structure (i.e. to generate a volume mesh). I found a suitable solution using [Meshmixer](http://www.meshmixer.com/) as described in the following youtube video: [How to do 3D Lattice Infill in Meshmixer - A Proper Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffmg1E3m1Ak). But now, I want to generate such lattice structures automatically. Therefore, I'm looking for a (favor, C++) framework to generate such lattice structures. The input could be a surface mesh, defining an implicit domain that should be filled. I found the following C++ frameworks for mesh processing/generation:

- [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/)
- [libigl](https://github.com/libigl/libigl)
- [TetGen](http://wias-berlin.de/software/tetgen/)
- [OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/).

However, as far as I know none of them can generate lattice structures to fill surface meshes. It's only possible to generate closed tetrahedrals (for an example using CGAL see [3D Mesh Generation](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/index.html)). After searching the internet  again I found the following MATLAB program:

- [STL Lattice Generator](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48373-stl-lattice-generator?s_tid=gn_loc_drop).

It sounds very promissing - but - it is not possible to fill an implicit domain defined by a surface mesh.

Are there any other (C++) frameworks? Or do I need to implement an own method in order to fill a surface mesh with a lattice structure.